# Stripe integration in Asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe in my asp.net application. I am using Visual Studio 17 and target .Net framework is 4.6.1

[The post i followed exactly](https://www.codementor.io/sovitpoudel/asp-net-integration-with-stripe-arm46wai0)

Below is my controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Stripe;

namespace DonationProgram.Controllers
{
    public class DonationController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Donation
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var stripePublishKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pk_test_Ih2IeiHk6PmK19pdh7UPijhr"];
            ViewBag.StripePublishKey = stripePublishKey;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
        {
            var customers = new StripeCustomerService();
            var charges = new StripeChargeService();

            var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Email = stripeEmail,
                SourceToken = stripeToken
            });

            var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 500,//charge in cents
                Description = "Sample Charge",
                Currency = "usd",
                CustomerId = customer.Id
            });

            // further application specific code goes here

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

But there are errors in `new StripeCustomerService()`, `new StripeChargeService()` & `new StripeCustomerCreateOptions` saying that "the type or namespace could not be found" though i am using Stripe namespace.

Comment: Stripe working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that blog post is incorrect. What you should really be using is `Stripe.CustomerCreateOptions` or just `CustomerCreateOptions`. Likewise for other classes error is reporting.

For example. There is no class `StripeCustomerCreateOptions` in the [stripe-dotnet repo](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet), but there is just `CustomerCreateOptions` defined [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Services/Customers/CustomerCreateOptions.cs).

**Update.** A bit more digging through the repo reveals that the blog post was correct at some point, but got out of date. There was a [commit](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/commit/b10cbdf34eb9305dc39466d1c09278da264367e0#diff-6c16cf167021d1209a3e9c56976b111b) in August'18 that removed `Stripe` prefix from all the customer facing API classes.

Comment: I suffered a bit for the "Stripe" prefix. Thank you,  that solved my problem.

Comment: Stripe working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET